# Ideals of set of functions from real to real

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification, ideals

I'm looking to prove the following is an ideal of the set of functions from real numbers to real:
a)the set of all f such that f(x) = 0 for every rational x 
b) the set of all f such that f(0) = 0

Comment: Then verify that those sets satisfy the properties of an ideal. Where did you find difficulty in that?

Answer (score 0):

look the very definition of an ideal: you have to check that your set is a subgroup for the addition, and stable by multiplication by any $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

It straightforward, right?